# Java: Runtime.getRuntime().exec() system call error/Failure

Tags: java, linux, operating-system, system

I have a shell script which returns the disk usage of a given directory path and Unix user. I would like to execute this command with java system call and below is my code. When I run the command in terminal, it perfectly works, but Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) gives the following error. Any idea what causing this error to happen?

Terminal (works): > usr/bin/status storage --format json "\"path='/a/b/c/d' && User='testuser'

Error:
line: Parameter "path='/a/b/c/d' is not defined
exit: 234

```
String s;
Process p;
try {
    String cmd = "/usr/bin/status storage --format json \"path='/a/b/c/d' && User='testuser'\"";
    System.out.println(cmd); //running printed output in terminal works, not in exec() call
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println("line: " + s);
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
    p.destroy();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: maybe [Single quote Issue when executing Linux command in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25515187/85421) or [Executing jar file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37561657/85421) More, if you know what to [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+exec+stringtokenizer) (not that trivial)

Comment: The 'Executing jar file in java link' worked, Thanks!